# Creating dynamic lightning component after clicking button

Tags: lightning

How to create the component dynamically based on button click.Here component isnt creating properly and it causes error while loading the page.Whats the root cause?

```
 <aura:component> 
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
   <p>Dynamically created button</p>
    {!v.body}
</aura:component>
```

====java script controller====
({

```
      doInit : function(cmp) {
         $A.createComponent(
        "ui:button",
        {
            "aura:id": "findableAuraId",
            "label": "Press Me",
            "press": cmp.getReference("c.handlePress")
        },
        function(newButton, status, errorMessage){
            //Add the new button to the body array
            if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                var body = cmp.get("v.body");
                body.push(newButton);
                cmp.set("v.body", body);
            }
            else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
                // Show offline error
            }
                else if (status === "ERROR") {
                    console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
                    // Show error message
                }
        }
    );
},
handlePress : function(cmp) {
    $A.createComponent(
        "c:ProposalCenter",
        {

        },
        function(newButton, status, errorMessage){
            //Add the new button to the body array
            if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                var body = cmp.get("v.body");
                body.push(newButton);
                cmp.set("v.body", body);
            }
            else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
                // Show offline error
            }
                else if (status === "ERROR") {
                    console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
                    // Show error message
                }
         }
     );
 },
```

})

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: At the time of Page Load : Error during init [Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined]

Comment: This error doesn't seem to be coming from the code you have pasted here. Provide any other component, controller if you have in this scope.

Comment: I have revisited my code.. that error is coming from  handlePress function call in Java script..how to resolve it

Comment: Please update your question with handlePress function for better suggestions. The error is coming because you tried to access apply property of some variable which was null or undefined.

Comment: okay got it.Thanks....I'am just trying to do Navigation to that component [Proposalcenter]..Is it possible??

Comment: Yes, create the component in handlePress function like you created the ui:button on init.

Comment: I have tried that ..Its working fine..Thank you @Santanu Halder...But If I press the button i want that page[its working] ..again i don't want that press button after pressing it has to disable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error you were getting:

> Error during init [Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined]

The error is coming because you tried to access apply property of some variable which was null or undefined.

And to answer your last question in the comments section:

When you create a new component and adding it into the body and if you want to hide the current items from the body, make sure to empty the body array before adding the new item in it.

```
var body = cmp.get("v.body");
body = []; //emptying the existing elements.
body.push(newButton);
cmp.set("v.body", body);
```

If you have multiple items in body array and you want to delete a specific one, you need to have a for loop and traverse through all of the items in body and remove the one you want.

Comment: Still Iam getting press button..After adding those lines in the code..

Comment: Please don't blindly copy the codes you get here. We don't know what you have in your class/component. Make sure your body array is blank after the emptying and then add the new component.

Comment: Santanu > Il y empty the body but do not destroy the components alreaady instanciated inside, u can create "ghost components" who still handle events ! On our ISV, we use if PrevBody != null -> PrevBody[0].destroy(); ( even iterate on body elements if there can be several cmps in there )

Comment: @SantanuHalder Okay .. If  we empty the body but we don't destroy the component.   means any way press button will appear every time..My question is after pressing the button I have to make that button as disable.I hope you understand.Thank you ....